# Create fields in runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a new app where users can be created. For example:

```
User 
name:string, email:string
```

One of the requirements of the app is that the administrator in the future will be able to create new fields for this user. For example:

```
User 
name:string, email:string, surname:string
```

So the administrator will be able to create new fields without telling the developer to do it.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: what backend are you using is it SQL or non-SQL? Seems non-SQL backends like CouchDB can support this but otherwise [This Post](http://blog.obiefernandez.com/content/2012/02/metaprogramming-your-activerecord-objects-at-runtime.html) might help or look at ActiveRecord::Schema#define as this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490473/build-a-table-at-runtime-in-ruby-on-rails) suggests

Comment: You can also serialize arbitrary hashes if you're not in a NoSQL DB, but you really don't want to alter your model itself at runtime.

Comment: At the moment I havent decide for a SQL or a non-SQL db. So I can decide :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a model called `Field` to store the fields (name, email, etc). Each user will have many fields and each field belongs to many users, so you need a association class (`UserFields`).

```
|------|          |-----------|            |-------|
| User |1--------*| UserField |*----------1| Field |
|------|          |-----------|            |-------|
```

For example:

```
 users          users_fields                         fields
-------        -------------                        --------
id             userd_id   field_id  value           id   name
1              1          1         my name         1    name
               1          2         my address      2    address
               1          3         my email        3    email
```

Take a look on the rails guide to see how to set a has many through association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I have been trying to buid the form for creating fields for the user using the structure of users, users_fields and fields. Any idea of how can this be achived in rails?

Comment: @VictorDonet: You can use nested form to achieve it. I have made an example a years ago (https://github.com/gabrielhilal/nested_form). In this example I have used `user`, `line` and `category`, in your case it should be `user`, `user_field` and `field`. Fell free to download this repo and play with that... I hope it helps...

Comment: I've tried this solution of users,users_fields, fields and it doesn't work the way I expected. The reason is because the value of the fields can have different types boolean, text, etc and they will have different posible values.
For example I want the user to be able to create a new field gender. This field will be a radiobutton with 2 options male or female. And all the views for this field have to be generated.